# Accessing the running RSpec/Steak scenario's name

Tags: ruby, logging, rspec

I want to have a before(:each) for my test suite that logs the name of the running scenario to the test log, so I can analyze it later and know which test did what. Is this possible? :)

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can access it via `example.description`. See related [rspec feature](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/features/metadata/current_example.feature).

Comment: update: it is now `RSpec.current_example.description`